# Please explain about Chebyshev's inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, integral-inequality

I am studying Probability theory.

I met Chebyshev's inequality chapter.

I understood that Chebyshev's inequality is

$$
P\left({|X-\mu| \ge \epsilon}\right) \le \frac{Var(X)}{\epsilon^2}
$$

And I tried to solve the question.

$\mbox{Given that }E(X)=100\mbox{ and } V(X)=625,\\ \mbox{Find the upper bound of }P(X\ge125)\mbox{ using Chebyshev's inequality.}$

---

My trial:
$$
P(X\ge125) =P(X-100 \ge 25) \le P(|X-100| \ge 25) \le\frac{Var(X)}{25^2} = 1\\
\therefore P(X\ge125) \le 1
$$

---

But my teacher told me that the answer is $\displaystyle\frac12$.

Her trial:
$$
P(X\ge125) =P(X-100 \ge 25)=\frac12P(|X-100| \ge 25) \le \frac{Var(X)}{25^2} = 1\\
\therefore \therefore P(X\ge125) \le \frac12
$$

---

Is is possible to change like the following without random variable $X$ is symmetry?

$$P(X-100 \ge 25) = \frac12P(|X-100| \ge 25)$$

I'm casting doubt on the following X.

[image]

I think $P(X-100 \ge 25) = \frac12P(|X-100| \ge 25)$ is impossible for random variable following the above picture.

Comment: Well seeing as how all probabilities are between 0 and 1 your answer of less than or equal to 1 is not so descriptive

Comment: Yes, so I added this word "so chebyshev inquality is not effiective in this case." into answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One cannot in general turn the Chebyshev Inequality into a correct one-sided inequality by simply dividing the tail probability by $2$.

However, there *are* one-sided inequalities, for example the [Cantelli Inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantelli%27s_inequality)  This says that $$\Pr(X-\mu\ge \epsilon)\le \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+\epsilon^2}.$$
In your case, the Cantelli Inequality yields a probability bound of $\frac{625}{625+625}$, exactly the bound mentioned by your teacher.

Comment: You mean 1/2 is correct?

Comment: The answer says onne **cannot** $\dots$. The $1/2$ is not a correct use of the Chebyshev Inequality.

Comment: André Nicolas, so the prof is wrong? I was kind of surprised by the 1/2. I think it assumes X is symmetric or something

Comment: It may be a matter of semantics. The current answer has more detail than the previous one. If the prof was using the Cantelli bound, sometimes called the Cantelli-Chebyshev bound, then one gets $\frac{1}{2}$. But this is not the classical Chebyshev Inequality, and in general one cannot take the Chebyshev bound and divide by $2$ to get a one-sided bound.

Comment: Ah you mean the prof may have used 'Chebyshev's Inequality' to refer to what you call the 'Cantelli inequality' ?

Comment: Maybe. It depends on whether the classical Chebyshev inequality you quoted is from your course notes, or something you found yourself.