# How many attempts required for independent events to occur at least $N$ times with a set probability

Tags: probability

I have a problem where independent events happen each with a success rate of $0.17.$
I would like to calculate how many times I would need to carry out the event to be $90\%$ certain that there have been at least $36$ successes.

I believe similar questions have been asked before but I find the answers completely incomprehensible.

Comment: Are you familiar with the binomial distribution?

Comment: This is a Binomial, which might approximated by a Gaussian. For a not tight bound, you can resort to Chebyshev (or Cantelli) inequality https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1580734/312

Comment: Do you known any discrete probability distribution?

Comment: USe Chebychev, Paley-Zygmund, or Hoeffding / Bernstein  inequalities.

Comment: Would It be possible for somebody to walk through how to use some of the methods mentioned above or at least give a correct answer

Comment: Probably you would like to see *at least* 36 successes...

Comment: How about you try one of those methods and ask specific questions if you run into specific difficulties ?

Comment: I am clueless as to what I am looking at when I look them up or how to use them - I feel that to use them I need knowledge of all of the notation and several other functions which I simply do not have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each event $E_i$ can be thought of as a bernoulli variable with probability of success as $0.17$. So we have $\mathbb P[E_i] = 0.17$

The sum of n bernoulli variables is $S_n = E_1+\dots+E_n \sim binom(n,p)$. Then the expected number of successes with n events $\{E_1,\dots,E_n\}$ is $np = 0.17n$. Further, the variance of the number of successes is $npq = n\times 0.17\times 0.83 = 0.1411 n$.

Now note that by the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), when independent random variables are added, their sum tends toward a normal distribution.

The mean and variance of the normal distribution we already found as $0.17n,0.1411n$. Therefore the required sum has distribution $\mathcal N(0.17n,0.1411n)$.

Finally, we want 90% confidence interval that there are more than 36 successes. Given a normal distribution, we can say with 90% confidence that the values will lie in the interval: $(\mu - z(0.9)\sigma,\mu + z(0.9)\sigma)$.

In our case $\mu = 0.17n$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{0.1411n}$
Further, from normal tables, we can find the z value corresponding to 90% $= z(0.9) = 1.645$

Finally we have our equation: $36<0.17n-1.645\sqrt{0.1411n}$. We set this to equality to find the least such value of n, therefore we have $36=0.17n-1.645\sqrt{0.1411n}$.

Setting $\sqrt{n}=x$, we have the equation $0.17x^2 - 0.6179x - 36=0$, solving which we get $n=272$

Comment: pls see: for explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_steps and for a z table https://www.math.arizona.edu/~rsims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf
---
6th paragraph, what exactly do you want an explanation on?

Comment: thankyou - just researched it a bit and found out how to do it - I just got a bit confused with the difference between z-scores and z alpha/2